# Which resource folders do you recomment for tablet app?

Tags: android-layout, embedded-resource, android

At the moment, I set these resource folders:

```
/res
    /drawable
    /drawable-large-hdpi
    /layout
    /layout-port
    /layout-large-hdpi
```

`large-hdpi` folders are for Galaxy Tab, while others are for other tablets.

What additional resource folders do you suggest to add?

Comment: Is this app going to be exclusively on tablets? That is, are you setting android:normalScreens="false"? Are you targeting both 7" and 10" tablets? A tablet may have a large (or xlarge) screen, but the pixel density is possibly medium. Design your drawables for pixel density and don't use a qualifier for size. Design your layouts for size and let the OS choose the proper image size. You don't need to specify both qualifiers.

Comment: @EricCloninger Yes, tablet only. Large Hdpi and xlarge as well. all tablets. galaxy and similar will use large-hdpi resources, others from default directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use large-land, large-port, xlarge-land, & xlarge-port, but I would not recommend this.

I would recommend filtering drawables based on pixel density & filtering layouts based on screen size. Also, read [THIS](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: I am aware of this link, but tablets like galaxy tab are not registered "by rules". can you write an example of filtering per pixel density and per screen size?

Answer (score -1):

```
  drawable-large
```

i am using this folder for all tablet

Comment: did you test it on real devices? there must be problems with this on different tablets